# pulling columns from two tables when there is a group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which returns the custref having multiple tetranumbers(1 to n mapping)

```
select *
  from cdsheader
 where custref in(select custref
                    from(select *
                           from cdsheader h,custandaddr c
                          where h.custref = c.cwdocid
                            and c.addresstype = 'C')
                   group by custref
                  having count(distinct( tetranumber )) > 1)
```

count 5144

My objective is to pull the matching address details along with the above result, but I guess I am missing something here.

Something like...

```
select a.cworderid,a.cwcreated,a.organisationtype,a.custref,a.tetranumber,
       b.buildingname,b.streetname,b.posttown,b.postcode,b.country
  from cdsheader a,custandaddr b
 where custref in (select custref
                     from cdsheader h,custandaddr c
                    where h.custref = c.cwdocid
                      and c.addresstype = 'C')
                    group by custref
                   having count(distinct( tetranumber )) > 1)
 order by a.custref,a.tetranumber,a.cworderid;
```

Comment: you're missing a join on table A->B in the 2nd SQL.

Comment: where exactly am I missing the join ? could you try to modify the query ?

Comment: Techie, DazzaL is referring to the fact that you don't have any correlation in your `WHERE` clause between `a` and `b` - you're going to get a cartesian product, which probably isn't what you want (all headers with all addresses).  This is one of the biggest reasons the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) is avoided, in favor of explicitly specifying the joins.

Comment: thanks for the response Clockwork-Muse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than scanning your table twice ,create a inline view and fetch the result using analytical function .Please test

```
SELECT     inner.cworderid,
           inner.cwcreated,
           inner.organisationtype,
           inner.custref,
           inner.tetranumber,
           inner.buildingname,
           inner.streetname,
           inner.posttown,
           inner.postcode,
           inner.country
FROM(           
  SELECT   h.cworderid,
           h.cwcreated,
           h.organisationtype,
           h.custref,
           h.tetranumber,
           c.buildingname,
           c.streetname,
           c.posttown,
           c.postcode,
           c.country,
           COUNT(DISTINCT tetranumber) OVER(PARTITION BY h.custref) cnt
    FROM   cdsheader h, custandaddr c
    WHERE  h.custref = c.cwdocid 
       AND c.addresstype = 'C'
      )inner
  WHERE inner.cnt>1 
 ORDER BY inner.custref, inner.tetranumber, inner.cworderid;
```

Comment: cool thanks Gaurav, after modifying my query it worked, but your approach is much better way of handling the situation

Answer (score 0):

By modifying the query (included one more join) it worked for me...but Gaurav answer is a better way

```
select 
     a.cworderid,a.cwcreated, a.organisationtype, a.custref, a.tetranumber, b.buildingname,     b.streetname, b.posttown, b.postcode, b.country
    from custandaddr b, cdsheader a where b.cwdocid = a.custref and custref in(
    select custref from(
    select * from cdsheader h, custandaddr c where h.custref=c.cwdocid and c.addresstype = 'C')
    group by custref having count(distinct(tetranumber))>1)
    order by a.custref, a.tetranumber, a.cworderid
```